# std::vector Updating at position iOffset with N number of values

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have `std::vector<int> around`, in which I need to update(/overwrite) **N** values starting at position **X**.

Imagine a list of vertices holding vertexes for the whole room.

Randomly, you move the chair and you need to update only those vertices which
belong to the chair, so you need to update a set of chair vertices within the whole room vertices list.

Pseudocode:

```
void CVertexBuffer::Update(int iOffset, const std::vector<tVertex>& vVerticesList)
{

  // Update VAO
     ...


  //
  // Update m_vVertices (holding current vertices list) 
  // with vVerticesList (holding updated vertices data )
  // starting at position iOffset
  // The size of m_vVertices never changes
  // 
  // The Dumb way ( just for pseudocoding )

  for(int a = iOffset; a < vVerticesList.size(); a++)
  {
     m_vVertices[a] = vVerticesList[a-iOffset];
  }
}
```

Is there something I can use within `std::vector` to do that ?

Comment: "The size of m_vVertices never changes" -- then it's not called "appending", it's called "assigning", "overwriting", etc.

Comment: @SteveJessop - Yes, sorry, you're right - i missed a plot here, will update the post in a sec.

Comment: Doesn't you question seem a bit confusing?

Comment: @Rohit - no after it has been updated. What is confusing you now ?

Comment: iOffset with N number of values! Simplicity of your question would help other people also to find this answer when they search.

Comment: @Rohit - Sure i will try my best next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly use `std::copy`:

```
 std::copy(vVerticesList.begin(), vVerticesList.end(), 
                                         m_vVertices.begin() + iOffset);
```

Comment: This seems to answer his question as he wanted to ask it. To answer his question as he actually asked it (<i>appending data</i>), the vector class itself has functions for that: `m_vVertices.insert(m_vVertices.end(), vVerticesList.begin() + iOffset, vVerticesList.end());`

Comment: @Geoff_Montee No! That inserts elements, it doesn't overwrite the existing ones.

Comment: Yes, I know. Appending is inserting to the end. That is why I said that this call would answer the question as he actually asked it. I didn't say that's what he wanted! Your answer definitely satisfies what he wanted--just not what he asked for.

Comment: @Geoff_Montee yes, but he's not talking about appending. He wants previous values overwritten.

Comment: I was referring to where he said: I have std::vector around, in which i need to append N values starting at position X. He definitely does mention appending.

Comment: @All - thank you all for a quick reply.
And sorry for the mistaken subject - it has been corrected.